# Criar uma nova variável em um dataframe a partir da condição de uma variável já existente

Tags: python, pandas, variáveis, dataframe, condição

Estou estudando python e pandas com um banco de dados no qual eu tenho as seguintes variáveis para a idade:

NU_IDADE_N = Correspondente ao número da idade

&

TP_IDADE = Correspondente ao tipo da idade, sendo:
1 - dias
2 - meses
3 - anos

| NU_IDADE_N | TP_IDADE |
| --- | --- |
| 19 | 3 |
| 21 | 2 |
| 56 | 1 |
| 12 | 3 |

Eu gostaria de criar uma terceira variável, 'IDADEANOS', na qual se TP_IDADE != de 3 então IDADEANOS = 0

A idéia que eu tive era da seguinte forma:

```
dados["IDADEANOS"] = dados["NU_IDADE_N"] 

if dados["TP_IDADE"] != 3:
    dados["IDADEANOS"] ==0
```

Obviamente não funcionou e apesar de ser algo bem simples eu não encontrei nada na documentação que me auxilie com essa situação especificamente.

Então se alguém tiver uma solução serei muito grato.

Desde já agradeço pela atenção.

Comment: Na linha abaixo do `if dados["TP_IDADE"] != 3:` não deveria ser `dados["IDADEANOS"] = 0`? Da forma atual está fazendo uma comparação e não uma atribuição.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crie um função que descreva a lógica que você quer aplicar para cada uma das linhas do seu dataframe:

```
def func(linha):
    if linha['TP_IDADE'] != 3:
        return 0
    else:
        return linha['NU_IDADE_N']
```

Depois, use `df.apply` para aplicar essa função a elementos do seu dataframe, passando também o argumento `axis=1` para determinar que a função deve ser aplicada linha-a-linha:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'NU_IDADE_N': [19, 21, 56, 12],
    'TP_IDADE': [3, 2, 1, 3],
})

df['IDADEANOS'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
print(df)
```

output:

```
   NU_IDADE_N  TP_IDADE  IDADEANOS
0          19         3         19
1          21         2          0
2          56         1          0
3          12         3         12
```

Answer (score 3):

para este caso você pode utilizar o numpy para auxiliar na sua condicional

```py
import pandas
import numpy as np

obj = [
{"NU_IDADE_N": 19,"TP_IDADE": 3},
{"NU_IDADE_N": 21,"TP_IDADE": 2},
{"NU_IDADE_N": 56,"TP_IDADE": 1},
{"NU_IDADE_N": 12,"TP_IDADE": 3}
]

df = pandas.DataFrame(obj)

df['IDADEANOS'] = np.where(df['TP_IDADE']!=3, 0, df['NU_IDADE_N'])
df.head()

#output
NU_IDADE_N  TP_IDADE    IDADEANOS
19             3           19
21             2            0
56             1            0
12             3           12
```